# Convert C# to Ruby - MD5 and Base 64 a String

Tags: c#, ruby

I have this code that I need to convert to ruby, this snippet is to create a security key used for a particular API.  The string that I am encrypting is a JSON object.

Should I use `Digest::MD5.hexdigest()` or `Digest::MD5.digest()`?

**C# Code**

```
string strResponse = "[{\"Key\":\"BookNumber\", \"Value\"=>\"BJAK123\"},{\"Key\"=>\"AuthorCode\", \"Value\"=>\"BNA123\"}]";

using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    byte[] bPayload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strPayload);
    byte[] bPayloadHash = md5.ComputeHash(bPayload);

    strPayloadBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bPayloadHash);
}
```

**Ruby Code**

```
payload = [{"Key"=>"BookNumber", "Value"=>"BJAK123"},{"Key"=>"AuthorCode", "Value"=>"BNA123"}]


utf8_params = payload.to_json.force_encoding("iso-8859-1").force_encoding("utf-8")
payload_base64 = Base64.encode64(Digest::MD5.hexdigest(utf8_params))
```

Comment: @NeilSlater sorry about that, see updated details.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. There is a difference between writing a hash verifier in Ruby for something that the C# produces, or simply reconstructing the code in order for Ruby and C# to use the same API. Is the C# code part of a system that is sending code to the Ruby shown or vice-versa (in which case you may need to care about how the JSON is serialised maybe differently by Ruby or C#)? If not, then the answer is possible from the code you show.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
payload_base64 = Digest::MD5.base64digest(utf8_params)
```

as `Digest::MD5.hexdigest` produces a hex string of digest, whereas C# code is performing `base64` encoding of the digest.